# XSL - How to group a specific number of elements

Tags: xslt

I have got several paragraphs and I want to display only 5 of them on a single page. To do that I am using the keep-together="always" attribute.

for the following input:

```
<paragraphs>
    <paragraph/>
    <paragraph/>
    <paragraph/>
    <paragraph/>
    <paragraph/>
    <paragraph/>
    <paragraph/>
    <paragraph/>
    <paragraph/>
    <paragraph/>
</paragraphs>
```

I would like to get something like that:

```
<fo:block keep-together="always">
    <paragraph/>
    <paragraph/>
    <paragraph/>
    <paragraph/>
    <paragraph/>
</fo:block>
<fo:block keep-together="always">
    <paragraph/>
    <paragraph/>
    <paragraph/>
    <paragraph/>
    <paragraph/>
</fo:block>
```

I first tried something like the following:

```
  <xsl:template match="paragraphs">
    <fo:block keep-together="always">
      <xsl:for-each select="paragraph">
        <xsl:if test="position() mod(5) = 1 and not(position() = 1)">
          </fo:block>
          <fo:block keep-together="always">
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </fo:block>
  </xsl:template>
```

but the problem is it does not compile as the closing of fo:block is inside a xsl:if (sax parser exception when compiling).

Does anyone have an idea of how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track with checking the position() mod 5, but the approach you need to take is  rather than selecting all **paragraph** elements and checking the position with an **xsl:if**, is to change the **xsl:for-each** to select only the 1st, 6th, 11th, etc elements

```
<xsl:for-each select="paragraph[position() mod 5 = 1]">
```

This would be the basis for your **fo:block**. And within this block, you can then select all the **paragraph** elements that make up the block.

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="self::*|following-sibling::paragraph[position() &lt; 5]"/>
```

Here is the full XSLT. Note I have parameterised the '5' to make it easy to adjust the number of paragraphs per block.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:param name="para" select="5" />

   <xsl:template match="paragraphs">
      <xsl:for-each select="paragraph[position() mod $para = 1]">
         <fo:block keep-together="always">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="self::*|following-sibling::paragraph[position() &lt; $para]"/>
         </fo:block>
      </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="paragraph">
      <xsl:copy-of select="." />
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```